# memory leak in a for loop

Tags: c, memory-leaks, for-loop, valgrind

```
for(k=i; k<MAXRECORDS; k++) {
    if(slist->servers_ptr[k+1] != NULL) {
        slist->servers_ptr[k] = slist->servers_ptr[k+1];
    } else slist->servers_ptr[k] = NULL;
}
```

When I run valgrind, I get an error of invalid size 8.

I assume this has something to do with a border case in my for loop, but I don't understand logically how it's happening.

EDIT: It was pointed out that on the last round of the for loop, accessing servers_ptr[k+1] is outside of the array, causing valgrind errors. I have since updated my code to:

```
for(k=i; k<MAXRECORDS-1; k++) {
        if(slist->servers_ptr[k+1] != NULL) {
                slist->servers_ptr[k] = slist->servers_ptr[k+1];
                if(k==MAXRECORDS-2)slist->servers_ptr[k+1] = NULL;
        } else slist->servers_ptr[k] = NULL;
}
```

I still get the errors in valgrind. Did I update it incorrectly?

Comment: MAXRECORDS = 10, and slist->servers_ptr[] is size MAXRECORDS

Comment: That is not a memory leak, The Valgrind message tells you that you are overwritting or overreading the bounds of an allocated memory(in your case array)

Comment: Did you declare `servers_ptr` as `servers_ptr[MAXRECORDS+1]`? Otherwise, you are reading past its end when `k = MAXRECORDS-1`.

Comment: Add the extra information to the question, not as a comment.  I've done it for you this time, but for the future.  (You could delete the comment that I've transferred for you, though; that I can't do.)

Comment: Thx for the replies, guys. it's declared as servers_ptr[MAXRECORDS]. I updated my question, does my solution fix it, logically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost certainly because you're going beyond the end of the array. The maximum value of `k` is `MAXRECORDS-1` and you're using `k+1` in your expressions.

That means you'll be accessing `array[MAXRECORDS]` where the index should be limited to between `0` and `MAXRECORDS - 1` inclusive.

It's difficult to see what you're trying to do without more context but the fix *may* be as simple as using `k < MAXRECORDS - 1` as the `for` loop continuing condition (the bit in the middle):

```
for (k = i; k < MAXRECORDS - 1; k++) {
```

The *other* possibility is an invalid value of `i`, like `-1` for example, which would cause the problem at the other end of the array. This is probably less likely since I'm assuming you're deleting element `i` by shifting all the other elements down (as in: `i` will be set to a valid index).

---

That's not a memory *leak* by the way, simply a memory corruption. Memory leaks are when you allocate memory and then lose the pointers to them so that they can never be freed, something like:

```
char *x;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    x = malloc (64);
```

where only the *last* allocation is accessible.

---

By the way, if a shuffling deletion is what you're after, it would be better done (in my opinion) as:

```
// For every element where there's a non-NULL next element,
// shift that element down. Then force the last element to
// be NULL (it will have been shifted down already).  

for (k = i; (k < MAXRECORDS - 1) && (slist->servers_ptr[k+1] != NULL); k++)
    slist->servers_ptr[k] = slist->servers_ptr[k+1];
slist->servers_ptr[k] = NULL;
```

The extra condition stops where the next element is NULL and places NULL into that position. That should work fine and has the advantage of being less complex.

Comment: That is much cleaner, you are right. Great explanation as well, I will give this a shot.

Answer (score 3):

If `slist->servers_ptr` is an array of size `MAXRECORDS` then accessing element `k+1` will be outside the bounds of the array when `k = MAXRECORDS - 1`.

Since 0 is the first element an array, 10 is the *eleventh* element of an array. An array of size 10 does not have an eleventh element.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

I updated the bounds in the for loop, but still get the same problems in valgrind.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the `for` condition, this looks like a bug:

```
if((slist->servers_ptr[k+1] != NULL)
```

because it will read past the end of the `servers_ptr` array.

Change the condition to `k < MAXRECORDS - 1`.

Comment: Thanks : ) I changed the condition in the for loop, but I'm still getting errors : (